# Netbeans installer

Tags: netbeans, installation

I downloaded Netbeans IDE 6.9 for windows. But I can't find installer option. Looked at http://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/generate_a_netbeans_platform_installer where it says that there is one, also on http://netbeans.org/community/releases/69/index.html it says that there is new feature "NetBeans Platform-based applications generate installers for most common operating systems".

Why I don't have one?

Comment: re: your don't have one comment.... which bundle did you install? Is there a check in the 'Show details' check box that is in the top right corner of the Installed panel?

Answer (score 2):

This property page is associated with a 'Module Suite' project and a 'NetBeans Platform Application' project.

After you create a 'NetBeans Modules->Module Suite' or 'NetBeans Module->NetBeans Platform Application' project, you need to MANUALLY ACTIVATE the "NetBeans Plugin Development" module.

1. Trigger the Plugins item on the
   Tools menu.
2. Select the Installed view.
3. Tick the Show details check box.
4. Scroll through the list to NetBeans
   Plugin Development
5. Tick the check box
6. Press the activate button

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/58022a41cf.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/58022a41cf.png)

I opened http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=189026 to request that the manual activation seems like a usability big.

Comment: Big thanks. I'm waiting to see what is the reason. It would be nice to post response here, can't add myself to cc for some reason.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have "NetBeans Plugin development" under Tools -> Plugins?

Answer (score 0):

The downloaded file should be a .exe which launches the installer when run. You may have downloaded the wrong version

If you downloaded a zip, it may be the non-install version. You can then simply run it from bin/netbeans.exe

Comment: I meant installers for developed app, not netbeans itself. For target OS deployment :)

Comment: @umpirksy perhaps you can reword your question to prevent answers like this

Answer (score 0):

In Netbeans Choose File->New Project and there under Project Categories choose Netbeans Modules -> Module suite.. give it a name and finish.. Now when this project is created right click on it and choose properties. There you will find the Installer under categories. Like you have seen in that blog. Hope that helped.